# Como converter um valor para float e int em python?

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo, interface

Olá, estou tentando converter um valor recebido de uma interface gráfica para int ou float, para fazer um software que resolva as equações de segundo grau.

```
layout = [  [sg.Text('Termo A:'), sg.InputText()], #os valores colocados aqui devem ser convertidos para float ou int
        [sg.Text('Termo B:'), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Termo C:'), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Ok(), sg.Cancel()]]
```

Já tentei varias coisas para fazer a conversão desses valores, porem nenhum funcionou.

```
elif event in (sg.ok, 'Ok'):
      valor_float = float(values)
      print (type(valor_float[0]))
```

No exemplo de cima da o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

estou usando a biblioteca PySimpleGUI. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Mas não vai dar certo mesmo. O valor que está tentando converter, segundo a mensagem de erro, é um dicionário. Provavelmente o valor alvo dessa conversão deve estar dentro desse dicionário.

Comment: Olá Eliseu, é importante [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Assim poderemos ajudar. Obrigado pela compreensão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu erro específica que você está tentando converte um dicionário para um float.

Nesse caso você precisa acessar o valor do seu dicionário para pode depois converte seus valores.

Por exemplo:

```
dicionario = { 'Termo A:':  '1234', 'Termo B:': '2.4','Termo C': '0.66'}

for x in dicionario.values():
    valor_float = float(x)
    print (type(valor_float))
```

O values() lê devolve todos os valores do seu dicionário, por isso você precisa usar um loop para imprimir cada valor, você também pode acessar o index especifico.

```
valor_float = float(dicionario['Termo B:'])
print (type(valor_float))
print(dicionario['Termo B:'])
```

Você pode ainda acessar sua chave/valor

```
for chave, valor in dicionario.items():
    if chave == 'Termo B:':
        valor_float = float(dicionario['Termo B:'])
        print (type(valor_float))
        print(f'{chave} Seu valor é {valor}')
```

Para converte para int basta usar a mesma logica e mudar o float para int.

Answer (score 0):

```
valor_float = float(valor)
valor_int = int(valor)
```

Comment: Olá, já havia tentado isso, isso aparece assim "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict", agradeço o comentário

Comment: @EliseuPeres esse erro aparece porque o `float` e o `int` aceitam apenas números ou strings para a conversão. Eles não aceitam um dicionário ou qualquer outro objeto.

Comment: memso por que nem tem como aceitar - qual seria o sentido de converter um dicionário, que é um mapa de nomes para valores, para um número? Na questão não é exibido de onde vem "values" ou o que ele é  - essa mensagem de erro diz que é um dicionário Você precisa saber o que dentro do dicionário quer transformar em float ou inteiro, e fazer a chamada equivalente passando esse valor.